# Can a domain redirect work for both http and https?

Tags: 7, configuration

Currently hosting a site on Pantheon and I would like to redirect traffic to a single domain. There is already a lot of links inside my site that are using:

http://example.com/somepage, http://www.example.com/somepage, https://example.com/somepage, https://www.example.com/somepage

Since Pantheon uses nginx I would have to use settings.php to redirect traffic. My Question is would it be possible to direct traffic to a single domain but it can be served in either http or https?

Some sample code:

```
// Require www.
if (isset($_SERVER['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT']) &&
  ($_SERVER['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT'] === 'live') &&
  (php_sapi_name() != "cli")) {
  if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'example.com' ||
      $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'https://example.com') {
    header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently');
    //or https://www.example.com
    header('Location: http://www.example.com'. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Nginx/settings.php

Try this: `$base_url = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`

- Apache/.htaccess:

You can simply add the following to your `.htaccess`. It will redirect all traffic from http://example.com and http://www.example.com to https://example.com. Put that below `RewriteEngine on`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Pantheon use nginx, no .htaccess available. It has to be done in php

Comment: Hm ok, since the OP says "Since Pantheon doesn't use nginx". Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. i meant to write since pantheon uses nginx

Comment: Np. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

If Drupal 7 Add the following to the end of your settings.php file (replace www.example.com):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT']) && php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  // Redirect to https://$primary_domain in the Live environment
  if ($_ENV['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT'] === 'live') {
    /** Replace www.example.com with your registered domain name */
    $primary_domain = 'www.example.com';
  }
  else {
    // Redirect to HTTPS on every Pantheon environment.
    $primary_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  }

  if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != $primary_domain
      || !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_SSL'])
      || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SSL'] != 'ON' ) {

    # Name transaction "redirect" in New Relic for improved reporting (optional)
    if (extension_loaded('newrelic')) {
      newrelic_name_transaction("redirect");
    }

    header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: https://'. $primary_domain . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
  }
}
```

**If Drupal 8 Add the following to the end of your settings.php file (replace www.example.com):**

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT']) && php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  // Redirect to https://$primary_domain in the Live environment
  if ($_ENV['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT'] === 'live') {
    /** Replace www.example.com with your registered domain name */
    $primary_domain = 'www.example.com';
  }
  else {
    // Redirect to HTTPS on every Pantheon environment.
    $primary_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  }

  if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != $primary_domain
      || !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_SSL'])
      || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SSL'] != 'ON' ) {

    # Name transaction "redirect" in New Relic for improved reporting (optional)
    if (extension_loaded('newrelic')) {
      newrelic_name_transaction("redirect");
    }

    header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: https://'. $primary_domain . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
  }
  // Drupal 8 Trusted Host Settings
  if (is_array($settings)) {
    $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array('^'. preg_quote($primary_domain) .'$');
  }
}
```

Here's [a link] [https://pantheon.io/docs/guides/launch/redirects/][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Sdg9.png) Redirect for SEO and Security
 Contribute

Make sure your DNS is setup & And you see the new domain/ https all in one turned on from Pantheon 
https://pantheon.io/docs/domains/#redirect-to-https-and-the-primary-domain 
(You need to see this for the Fastly CDN to use HTTPS
[image]